# Dell laptop motherboard issue

Tags: laptop, motherboard, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell laptop whose model number is Inspiron 1564.Its configuration is i3 processor, 4GB RAM and 320GB hard disk.

Recently it was not booting up.I took it to the service center and they mentioned that there is an issue with the motherboard and asked me to replace it.

My question is

1.Is it really worth to replace the motherboard since its price is bit hefty/go for a new laptop by adding some extra amount?

2.Will there be any issue after replacing the motherboard?

3.Even though the service center provides me with a 3 year warranty, I am still afraid.

If anybody have come across this kind of scenario, Kindly give me your suggestion

Comment: If it is under warranty then why are you paying for it?

Comment: @DaveRook:Laptop is 3 years old.It will be under warranty once I replace the motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my honest opinion unless the motherboard replacement is going to be under $150 I would cut your losses and get a better machine. You can always get a kit from a local best buy or radio shack that connects SATA to USB and get your files off of it.